# Why close() cannot be called on Closeable classes automatically?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, unmanaged, resource-cleanup

I don't understand. For example We have an variable of OutputStream type in a code, we should call close() on it when we stop using it, well why it wasn't implemented this way: GC calls close() itself when it does a clean up of this variable?

**Update:**
ok What I've concluded so far: releasing unmanaged recourses is not only about releasing memory what is more important that we don't now internal behavior behind it, it could exists a limitation on amount of this resource(number of connections/handlers) that's why we need to free them as soon as possible. Am I right? Because if it's all about the memory then I don't know why GC can't do the job just the way it does with managed recourses.

Comment: Most streams are implemented the finalise will call close, but there is no gurentee that finalise will be called. It's good practice to close your streams/readers when you k ow you're done with them

Comment: About your update: Exactly, it's not about memory but things external to the JVM.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`close` will in most cases eventually be called automatically by the GC through the `finalize` method (any class can have such `finalize` that is called by the GC when destroying the object; for `Closable` types that hold resources it will generally be implemented to call `close`). The issue of course is that you just don't have control over when this happens (if ever). It could be 10 sec or 10 min from when you stopped needing the object, still using up whatever resource was allocated. So it's good style to clean up your resource handles once you don't need them anymore.

Also, since Java 7 you can actually do this:

```
try (BufferedReader br =
               new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
    return br.readLine();
}
```

And `close` will be called automatically at the end of the try block.

See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for more details.

And finally, to the *why* there is `Closable` and things that need explicit closing in the first place, this is for resources that are not directly managed by the JVM and can hence also not automatically be reclaimed by GC. Such resources are for instances files, sockets or audio output.

Comment: ummm we don't care that local variables of non-closeable type won't be cleaned up simultaneously by GC why should we care about local variables of closeable type?

Comment: Because cloesable generally indicates that the corresponding object holds some system resource that is not under direct control of the JVM like a file descriptor for instance.

Comment: "corresponding object holds some system resource that is not under direct control of the JVM" but we still can call close() on it? so we do have control on it or what? If we do then GC does then it can does it itself, no?

Comment: Control was probably badly chosen. The JVM doesn't *manage* it, unlike the memory allocated by a variable for instance. So you will use up system resources that are shared with other processes and might be missing at some other place, but the JVM/GC does not know this. That's why you should release the resource as soon as possible.

Comment: I think this article might explain it better: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp03216/index.html

Comment: Please, whoever down voted, also explain why so I can fix it.

Comment: @inflagranti It was me, but in typing out my comment I decided to un-downvote. However, I'll still point out that (a) there's no guarantee that a class that implements `Closeable` will override `finalize` to call `close`; (b) `OutputStream` specifically [does _not_ do that](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/io/OutputStream.java). So the first sentence in your answer is incorrect, though the rest still holds and is good advice (hence the un-downvote).

Comment: @yshavit: Yes I left it out to not go into too much detail about that, but I will correct it, since it's not just missing, but indeed incorrect. I'm pretty sure that for things like File that do hold system resources though the finalizers will always call the close as a safety measure.

Comment: Also note that there's actually no guarantee in the JLS that a finalizer will ever be run; it only needs to be run if the JVM wants to reuse the object's memory. A JVM would be within its right to never reclaim an object's memory if it didn't need to, and the JLS doesn't say that finalizers have to be run before the program exits.